# Bootstrap 3 - Change Header Color, Container Error

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, header

All I want is that the header has a maroon color whereas the rest of the body is white, but it appears to have an extra white space on top. :(
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGktH.png

```css
/* bootstrap 3 helpers */

.navbar-form input,
.form-inline input {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
#nav.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
/* Create a medium height at 40px */

.navbar-md {
  min-height: 40px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-brand,
.navbar-md .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-brand {
  height: 40px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 6px 12px 6px 0px;
  padding: 6px 7px 6px 7px;
}
.navbar-md .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 19px;
}
.container#slider {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.container-full#headerC {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
}
/* RESPONSIVE HEADER*/

.navbar-header {
  background-image: url("bootstraplogo.png", "bootstraplogoslice1.png") background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
  background-position: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 479px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    background-size: auto auto;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    height: 45px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .navbar-header {
    background-size: auto 50px, 1px 50px;
  }
  .navbar-md#header {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
/* RESPONSIVE HEADER*/

.container-header {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.text-center {
  
}

p#headerP {
  display: inherit;
  padding: 30px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #76141D;
  font-family: "Josefin Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #8F1925;
}
p#subheader {
  display: inherit;
  margin: 0;

  padding: 0 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #E72635;
}

.container-full img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
}

/*  */
/* Custom container */
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>The University Digest</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container-full" id="headerC">
  
   <header class="masthead">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB2Vb5ACbTozhBh5PmikNRJ2uaQo3EMU7diYeOwZiodcvicmFI" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo">

 
     <p id="headerP">The University Digest</p>
     <p id="subheader">The Official Student Publication of Western Mindanao State University</p>
   </header>
  
 </div>

<!-- Navigation -->
 <div id="nav">
   <div class=" navbar-custom navbar navbar-inverse navbar-md">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Menu</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse navbar-md">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Articles <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Article</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Comics</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Editorial Cartoon</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Uncensored</a>
    </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Publications<b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Newsletters</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Magazine</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tejido</a>
    </li>
     </ul>
     <li><a href="#">Applications</a>
   </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">The Staff<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Editorial Board</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">By-Laws</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">WMSU Portal</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a>
    </li>
   </li>
   </ul> 
  </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
   


  <!-- News Ticker -->
  
  
  
  <!-- News Ticker -->

  <!-- Navigation -->
```

Subquestion: How do I place the logo near the first header? and align them to the left side of the screen?

So sorry for all the basic questions, I'm starting from scratch and the deadline is fast approaching :(

Comment: use firebug to check the styles for that element to see if there is  some padding or margin added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Romove padding-top:100px from your style and add margin: 0px; in body.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 479px)
body {
     padding-top: 100px;
     margin: 0px;
}
```

jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/k49nzp9f/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! but there is still a little space left on top :(

Comment: Add margin: 0px; in body.

Comment: oh crap it's still there :(

Comment: still the same :( check out the image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382845/bootstrap-3-navbar-cross-browser-issue/27382948#27382948

Comment: 'body {margin: 0px;}' add this code outside of media query