# Bootstrap 3 - NavBar Cross-browser issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I've made a page using Bootstrap. I made a flexible navbar and it looks great in Mozilla.
[image]

---

Whereas when I use Google Chrome, this happens

[image]

Why is this? And what is the solution to this?

```css
/* bootstrap 3 helpers */

.navbar-form input,
.form-inline input {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
#nav.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
/* Create a medium height at 40px */

.navbar-md {
  min-height: 40px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-brand,
.navbar-md .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-brand {
  height: 40px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 6px 12px 6px 0px;
  padding: 6px 7px 6px 7px;
}
.navbar-md .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 19px;
}
.container#slider {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.container-full#headerC {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #8F1925;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
/* RESPONSIVE HEADER*/

.navbar-header {
  background-image: url("bootstraplogo.png", "bootstraplogoslice1.png") background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
  background-position: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 479px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  
  .navbar-header {
    background-size: auto auto;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    height: 45px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .navbar-header {
    background-size: auto 50px, 1px 50px;
  }
  .navbar-md#header {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
/* RESPONSIVE HEADER*/

.container-header {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.text-center {
  
}

p#headerP {
  display: inherit;
  padding: 30px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #76141D;
  font-family: "Josefin Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #fff;
}
p#subheader {
  display: inherit;
  margin: 0;

  padding: 0 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #E72635;
}

.p img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
}

/*  */
/* Custom container */
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>The University Digest</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container-full" id="headerC">
  
   <header class="masthead">

 
     <p id="headerP">The University Digest</p>
     <p id="subheader">The Official Student Publication of Western Mindanao State University</p>
   </header>
  
 </div>

<!-- Navigation -->
 <div id="nav">
   <div class=" navbar-custom navbar navbar-inverse navbar-md">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Menu</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse navbar-md">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Articles <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Article</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Comics</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Editorial Cartoon</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Uncensored</a>
    </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Publications<b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Newsletters</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Magazine</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tejido</a>
    </li>
     </ul>
     <li><a href="#">Applications</a>
   </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">The Staff<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Editorial Board</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">By-Laws</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">WMSU Portal</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a>
    </li>
   </li>
   </ul> 
  </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the min-width thing, but I've tried manipulating it and I can't figure it out

Comment: I think it's just how Chrome renders the menu font.  You can see the letter spacing looks larger.

Comment: I noticed in the code snippet the issue doesn't exist and your menu fonts have been changed to use 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; instead of the custom "Josefin Slab" you have in your CSS code. @im1dermike was correct.

Comment: "Josefin Slab" is for the header fonts tho' I've tried manipulating them but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! :)

```
.navbar-nav {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}
```

The letter-spacing was the culprit. Thank you for the help @mijopabe.

Answer (score 1):

Include [Nicholas Gallagher's normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) CSS file before your other files and it will effectively reset browser preset padding/margin value, allowing them to adopt the same starting point. Do this by adding:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css">
```

in the `<head>` before your other CSS files.

An alternate solution is to use [YUI reset library](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/), instead. Do this by adding:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
```

in the `<head>` before your other CSS files.

Either one of them will allow for easier cross-browser compatibility when writing CSS.

**EDIT**

As was suggested subtly with a downvote,  a CSS reset ought to be included.  For trouble shooting sake AND to see if one CSS reset may be better, I would try one and then the other.  In any event, you'll learn how each helps in greater detail.

That being said, I researched some more and a similar case has been documented as being a Chrome bug (see here: https://superuser.com/questions/803601/text-size-suddenly-got-bigger-on-all-sites-on-google-chrome/803650#803650). Yes, browsers do render differently (not much, but enough to throw a designer off) and resetting CSS have been produced, but also try running your website in [Google Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html). It contains Chrome's newest features. If it runs as intended in Canary, that I would carry on as you were as those changes ought to eventually make their way over to Chrome.

What may also work is adding this to your CSS:

```
pre,
code,
kbd,
samp,
tt{
  font-family:monospace,monospace;
  font-size:1em;
}
```

These are elements that typically default to a monospace type-face in most browsers. The first of the two attributes pertains specifically to webkit based browsers.  Let me know if this works.

**EDIT 2**

Add this to your css and rewrite your classes with their respective font sizes. It's more of a *hack* and I discourage it, but it could help:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
  Body or other target {
    font-size: some px;      
  }
}
```

See if using a web-safe font like arial in both browsers renders different sizes. Sometime custom ones won't work the same.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! I've tried all that you've said but unfortunately none of them worked. Would you have any other advice to do this? the deadline is approaching and I am dying. haha

Comment: It also still gets messed up in Canary :(